# Building HTML5 based GUI in python

Tags: python, html, user-interface

Recently I was at a conference and one company had a software product which had a GUI written in HTML 5.It was rendered to the user via their custom built browser and looked quite good. I never heard of such concept and I am wondering if this is a common practice? I can see some benefits being able to produce flexible and stunning UI designs. Are there any tools available in Python? I assume you just need a browser able to render static pages with HTML and CSS. Also what would be the disadvantages of such approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I found https://github.com/html5lib

If you're going to send it in HTML5, I see no reason to build a browser though, there are already many browsers, that have more people working on them, you'd be hard pressed to beat something like Firefox or Chrome, unless you have a specific feature you want, and then a plugin might be better.  Generally building a custom browser like that is only useful if you either only want to do one very limited thing (like streaming a movie) or you want to use a different format (something like sending your version of HTML in an XML doc and parsing that and rendering it).

I also personally don't think Python is what you want to do this with, simply for a lack of compatibility with pretty much everything else at the current moment (not that you couldn't make things work, but it's not like you're going to download a Chrome plugin, change 3 lines of code and load it into your browser). I did see an example web browser in the wxPython docs, you could start there, I don't know what it does and what it doesn't do though unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, Seth, looks like an area I need to investigate more. Your reply good starting point.